# elasticsearch json java api

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch

I am trying to integrate elasticsearch with android app.

I need to get the jsonobject and print out the details for each id. First I need to try writing java class.

Can I just use json api or is there a elasticsearch api which is easier.

url:`http://www.dummy.com:9200/contacts/index/_search`

```
{
  "took": 10,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 1.0,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "contacts",
        "_type": "index",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "id": "c201",
          "name": "Johnny Depp",
          "email": "johnny_depp@gmail.com",
          "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
          "gender": "male",
          "phone": {
            "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
            "home": "00 000000",
            "office": "00 000000"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "contacts",
        "_type": "index",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "id": "c200",
          "name": "Ravi Tamada",
          "email": "ravi@gmail.com",
          "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
          "gender": "male",
          "phone": {
            "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
            "home": "00 000000",
            "office": "00 000000"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I have managed to get the json object from url.  But now to iterate through each of the contacts i am  getting org.json.JSONObject cannot be cast to org.json.JSONArray.  @BlackPOP

Comment: I feel the json object returned by elasticsearch is different from the normal json response string. Could you please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is several way to craete JSON object.. make it manually like string,use MAP.And  yes there is an helper class in ES that is XContentBuilder .for more info about that @[refer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/index_.html#helpers).

As per my considerations its better use any JSON API to create a valid object and easy to use.[refer](http://mavenhub.com/c/org/json/JSONObject/jar)

Comment: this is link only answer with dead links, this is why link only answers suck

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Answer not only have link, it also mention that you can use Any json builder, Map and  XContentBuilder provided by Elasticsearch. Links are for reference only..